# Login by STTwitterAPI error domain

Tags: ios, ios7, twitter, sttwitter

my app use login Twitter function, It worked on all device except iPhone 5. I don't know the reason so decide to post the question here. My code for login is:

```
self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:Twitter_API_KEY
                                             consumerSecret:Twitter_API_SECRET];


[self.twitter postTokenRequest:^(NSURL *url, NSString *oauthToken) {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

} authenticateInsteadOfAuthorize:NO
                forceLogin:@(YES)
                screenName:nil
             oauthCallback:@"com.twitteroauthcallback.sutrixsnowball://twitter_access_tokens/"
                errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"-- error: %@", error);
                }];
```

But it's log the error when I run on iPhone 5:

```
Error Domain=STHTTPRequest Code=401 "HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized" UserInfo=0x178270040 {NSLocalizedDescription=HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized}
```

Comment: Maybe it's related to this issue: https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/issues/154

Comment: Please let me know in detail, I didn't see any way to fix it into the above link.

Comment: Maybe the keys are not valid? Maybe the device's clock is not accurate?

Comment: The key is valid, cause I can login success on another devices. Why device's clock related to this function?

Comment: Because OAuth uses a timestamp. Request will fail if client and server clocks are not synchronised.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's right, cause my device's clock set the wrong value.